# Is there any expresion in English that means " in the right meaning "

Tags: translation, parentheticals

In Arabic we say ¨in the right meaning¨ when we want to add an expression better than the first one.

E.g. ¨I am in best way today¨ or (in right meaning) ¨I am so happy¨.

Comment: We say "*In other words...*". Our sister site, [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) is specifically tailored for people who want to learn how to speak English and use the right words.

Comment: This morning I used "I'm *x*, well, *y* really". 'Really' or 'in fact' or 'to be honest' all work.

Comment: Or you can use "... to put it another way, ..."

Comment: *In better terms*, *more precisely*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spoken English, I would generally say "I mean" or " or rather" to say something better than I said it the first time.

For example, "I am in a good mood today. I mean, I am so happy."

OR, "I am in a good mood today, or rather I am so happy"

Answer (score -1):

"by which I mean"

Though to be honest several others already given seem to work too.